# How to measure import execution time

Tags: javascript, performance, ecmascript-5

How can I measure execution time of import without stepping inside it?

Let say I have code bellow.

---

*main.js*

```
const now = Date.now();
import './module';
console.log(`${Date.now() - now}ms`);
// shows 0ms
```

---

*module.js*

```
const now = Date.now();
let a = 0;
for(let i = 0; i < 1000 * 1000 * 1000, i++) a++;
console.log(`${Date.now() - now}ms`;
// shows 1000ms
```

Comment: I wonder if `import` behaves kind of like `var` in that it's elevated to top of the function but not available until it's declared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way I found to measure imported module execution time, is using require instead. It is good to determine slow modules and revert back to import.

```
const now = Date.now();
const module1 = require('./module1');
console.log(`module1: ${Date.now() - now}ms`);
const module2 = require('./module2');
console.log(`module2: ${Date.now() - now}ms`);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your *main.js* doesn't work because no code of the module is executed until all imported dependencies have been loaded and initialised (executed). The two `Date.now()` calls will always run immediately after each other, resulting in the output of 0ms.

You would need to load another module before the measured *module.js* to take the start time:

```
// main.js
import { now as start } from 'beginMeasure';
import './module';
const end = Date.now();
console.log(`${end - start}ms`);
```

```
// beginMeasure.js
export const now = Date.now();
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, can you advice what to do if I have multiple import in row?

Comment: Importing the same module multiple times will have no effect :-) But you'd need to do `import start1 from 'beginMeasure1'; import './module1'; import start2 from 'beginMeasure2'; import './module2';` and so on for multiple imports. Really, you *should* just step inside the module, or use some other form of automatic tracing/profiling if you care about all your module execution times.